In Excel define name using name box with scope set to Sheet
Using the name box in Excel to define a new name. How can I set the scope of the name to the current sheet?
When I use the name box to define a new name, by default the scope of that name is the whole workbook. If I have a workbook with multiple sheets containing similar work, if I'm experimenting with something for example, then as soon as I try to define a name for a cell or range that I've used in another sheet then it doesn't work.
I know I can open the Name Manager or some other dialog boxes and define names and explicitly set the scope, but that takes 10 times as long as using the name box.
Is there no way to do this using the name box?

Use the name of the sheet before the defined name, e.g.
Sheet1!Myrange


I did try that and couldn't get it to work, but it was because I already had a worksheet scope variable with the same name. After seeing your answer and trying again I worked out the problem and got it to work. Thanks.
